# MongoDb query to page around a given ID in a List (not array)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have several apps and the requirement is that if the app sends us an ID(ObjectId) we should respond with a list of documents where the given ID is in the "center".

Maybe an example is easier to understand.

for example

in the DB we have

```
_id : 1
data : someData1

_id : 2
data : someData2

_id : 3
data : someData3

_id : 4
data : someData4

_id : 5
data : someData5
```

The app asks for _id : 3 and we should provide id 2,3 and 4.

We are looking for a way to put this in 1 query without processing on our side.

Extra problems :

- The data is updated regularly.
- The actual query is off course more then just find({}) and is ordered
  by a "publicationDate" but this is not detailed enough. (the date is
  up the the minute, not millisecond or something)
- Its impossible to put the position in the document itself because of the nature of the data and the inserts into this collection

We are also looking to do this in the aggregation framework but couldn't come up with a solution either.

Maybe the map-reduce but this query will be done continuously so I don't think this will be fast enough.

Any ideas are more then welcome

Kind regards

Comment: Are your `_id`s consecutively numbered integers like in your example or do you use auto-generated ObjectIDs?

Comment: Hi Philipp, the _ids are the usual auto-generated ObjectIds so there is no correlation between them that could help the ordering or position.

Comment: I think you will need to use two queries - one to get the first k documents greater than the document whose `_id` you are given and one to get the first k smaller documents. There isn't presently a way to ask for sorted documents centered at a given document and I don't think any sort of trick will help you in the general case of totally random inserts happening constantly (which is how I'm interpreting your 3rd bullet point).

Comment: That's indeed where we are stuck for the moment. But we are still trying to find a key in the data that we can use for this case. But no avail. So its not possible to query something like "where some field is bigger then givenField"